# How to cast all variables given as float

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to cast all of the variables that have been given by the user as floats, but my current code to do this is not working, and I don't know why.

```
s = input('Displacement')
u = input('Initial Velocity')
v = input('Final Velocity')
a = input('Acceleration')
t = input('Time')
m = input('Mass')
theta = input('Angle made with the horizontal')

for i in (s, u, v, a, t, m, theta):
    if i != '':
        i = float(i)
```

When I run this and try to do a calculation on one of the variables, for example

```
print (s**2)
```

I get the error message:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

How would I iterate through each variable and cast it as a float if it has a value?

Comment: `input()` function return a value of type `str` you need to convert it to `float` for example `float(input('Displacement'))`

Comment: My tip: Make a function called int_input that forces float input instead of input.

Comment: I made some changes (help,texts, func name) to my answer as it first tried to return an int. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @AntonvBR Yes it does, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new function, let us call it: `float_input()`

```
def float_input(text: str) -> float:
    """Makes sure that that user input is of type float"""
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input(text))
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a float.")
        else:
            return num

s = float_input('Displacement')
#...

print(s*2)
```

**But** then you could even do it like this (store data in a dictionary). Try it!!

```
def float_input(text: str) -> float:
    """Makes sure that that user input is of type float"""
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input(text))
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a float.")
        else:
            return num

items = [
    'Displacement',
    'Initial Velocity',
    'Final Velocity',
    'Acceleration',
    'Time',
    'Mass',
    'Angle made with the horizontal'
]

# Single line option:
#d = {item: int_input('{}: '.format(item)) for item in items}

# Multi-line option
d = {}
for item in items:
    v = float_input('{}: '.format(item))
    d[item] = v

# Print the stored-data    
print(d)
```

And then access values like this, e.g.:

```
d.get('Displacement')
```

Comment: I changed it from `int_input` from `float_input`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should convert to `float` at the point of data entry. This is probably the cleanest and most efficient method.

An alternative solution is to store your variables in a dictionary and then use a dictionary comprehension to convert to `float`. This has the design benefit of keeping your variables for a specific task linked.

The below example illustrates both methods using a dictionary. Neither of these methods apply validation. You should use `try` / `except ValueError` to ensure your inputs are valid at point of entry.

```
input_dict = {'s': 'Displacement', 'u': 'Initial Velocity', 'v': 'Final Velocity',
              'a': 'Acceleration', 't': 'Time', 'm': 'Mass',
              'theta': 'Angle made with the horizontal'}

var_dict = {}

# direct conversion to float
for k, v in input_dict.items():
    var_dict[k] = float(input(v))

# conversion to float in a separate step
for k, v in input_dict.items():
    var_dict[k] = input(v)

# dictionary comprehension to apply float conversion
var_dict = {k: float(v) if v != '' else v for k, v in var_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = float(i)
```

does not convert `s` to `float(s)`. `i` is only a temporary variable that changes on each iteration. You need to convert the type explictily on the variable, e.g.:

```
s = float(input('Displacement'))
```

Loop is not necessary.

You may use of course following command:

```
s = input('Displacement')
u = input('Initial Velocity')
v = input('Final Velocity')
a = input('Acceleration')
t = input('Time')
m = input('Mass')
theta = input('Angle made with the horizontal')

variables = [s, u, v, a, t, m, theta]

for num, i in enumerate(variables):
     if i != '':
        variables[num] = float(i)

s, u, v, a, t, m, theta = variables
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate it, or would I just need to do it for each variable?

Comment: @JoshuaPeacham There is a way to iterate over and change a set of local variables, but it's hacky and the wrong way to do things. Follow Anton's advice above. (And don't do it the way suggested in this answer; it's too easy to mix up the order when packing or unpacking the list, leading to variables getting each others' values.)